# crossfilter.js: group data by month

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

I have an array of objects, each with `Created` field (of type `Date`). Using crossfilter.js, I want to group this data by month. But it doesn't seem to work properly. Here's code:

To generate example data, I'm using [d3's time](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals) utilities:

```
var now = new Date();
var yearAgo = d3.time.year.offset(now, -1);
var after6months = d3.time.month.offset(now, 6);

// data[] will contain one object for each month in the range
var data = d3.time.month.range(yearAgo, after6months).map(function(date) {
    return {
        "Created": date,
        "Type": 'solid',
        "State": "Down"
    };
});

var cf = crossfilter(data);
var byDate = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.Created; });

// here I want to group by month and year, eg "October 2015"
var groupByMonth = byDate.group(function(date) { return d3.time.format("%B %Y")(date); });
var grouped = groupByMonth.all();
```

I would expect `grouped` to contain an element for each of the months in the range (for 1.5 year it would be 18), but I'm getting this:

`"[
    {
        "key": "October 2014",
        "value": 11
    },
    {
        "key": "September 2015",
        "value": 7
    }
]"`

Crossfilter is grouping all records under two groups, not desired 18. 
Am I doing something wrong here?

This code produces what I need, but I have to get it from crossfilter grouping:

```
var desired = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d3.time.format("%B %Y")(d.Created)})
    .rollup(function(group) { return group.length; })
    .entries(data);
```

Here's **jsFiddle** to play with http://jsfiddle.net/xxjpusa7/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle which does what I think you wanted it to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/xxjpusa7/4/

```
var now = new Date();
var yearAgo = d3.time.year.offset(now, -1);
var after6months = d3.time.month.offset(now, 6);

// data[] will contain one object for each month in the range
var data = d3.time.month.range(yearAgo, after6months).map(function (date) {
    return {
        "Created": date,
        "Type": 'solid',
        "State": "Down"
    };
});

var cf = crossfilter(data);
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%B %Y");

var byDate = cf.dimension(function (d) {
     return dateFormat(d.Created);
});

// Groups using the identity function
var groupByMonth = byDate.group();

var grouped = groupByMonth.all();

d3.select("div").text(JSON.stringify(grouped));
```

Basically the dimension was changed to index your data by the formatted date. And `byDate.group();` takes care of counting the unique indexes in your dimension (in this case the `month year`). It serves to think of group as a [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) instead of actual grouping.

Comment: thank you. It works. But I also need to filter the dataset by `Created`, ie I need the dimension to index by actual date?

Comment: @eagor Then you could use another dimension, I'm not 100% sure that's the only (or the best) way, but it does seem simpler.

Comment: Yup, using another dimension and filtering on that dimension would be the way to go in this scenario, as far as I can see.