# barChart plot with time dimension

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I would like to make a bar chart where x-axis is date e.g. 2017-08-12, and the y value is the number of data rows (i.e. records count) on the same date.

```
// get data into right format
var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
pageViews.forEach(function(d) {
    d['timestamp'] = dateFormat.parse(d['timestamp'].slice(0,10));
    d['timestamp'].setDate(1);
});

// Create Crossfilter instance
var cf = crossfilter(data);

var dateDim = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d['timestamp'];});

var numByDate = dateDim.group();
```

but if I do

```
console.log(numByDate.top(Infinity));
```

this returns 5 elements that are the first day of each month, so the group I have is in terms of Year-Month instead of Year-Month-Day, how can I resolve this?

I looked into this [crossfilter.js: group data by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746098/crossfilter-js-group-data-by-month), but it did not work, after using .all() I still get the same thing back.

And I tried this:

```
var numByDate = dateDim.group(function(d) {return d['timestamp'];});
```

it just returns me an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a result of my unfamiliarity with js and copy paste example code ...

The issue comes from misuse of the [setDate](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp) method,

```
setDate(1)
```

would just set the day of the month in the data to the first day, so the group method would only have several unique dates to work with.